# knife bootstrap is failing --node-ssl-verify-mode none is not working

Tags: chef-infra, knife

```
knife ec2 server create -E staging --node-name temp-chef-upgrade-test -f t2.small -r "recipe[base]"  -g xxxx -x ubuntu -I ami-49c9295f --subnet xxx -S xxxx -i xxxx --server-connect-attribute private_ip_address --node-ssl-verify-mode none  --no-node-verify-api-cert
```

I have set both of the below flags to my knife.rb as well

```
ssl_verify_mode          :verify_none
verify_api_cert          false
```

chef-client version

```
Chef 12.19.36
```

chef-server

```
12.13
```

Error

```
xx.xx.xx.xx [2017-03-28T10:02:03+00:00] ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: xx.xx.xx.xx - hostname "xx.xx.xx.xx" does not match the server certificate
xx.xx.xx.xx [2017-03-28T10:02:03+00:00] ERROR: SSL Error connecting to https://xx.xx.xx.xx/clients, retry 1/5
```

Comment: Which error are you getting ? The verify mode will only let a self signed certificate or a certificate with an unknown authority. If the names do not match, it will fail.

Comment: Certificates are supposed to be used with names, by default chef-server generate a certificate with the machine local hostname. you should fix your dns and use name to contact your serer, adding the IP into the self signed cert is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

To echo what Tensibai said in comments, the verify mode only controls checking the server certificate against the trusted CA database to check if the cert should be trusted. Even in the `none` verify mode (which you really shouldn't use), the certificate still has to match the requested hostname.

By default Chef Server generates a self-signed certificate using the FQDN of the machine it is installed on.

Answer (score 0):

Well first I am okay if don't verify ssl, which should work with `--node-ssl-verify-mode none` but some how it didnt adding `ssl_verify_mode :verify_none` in client.rb and chef-client still trying to do ssl verification.(so i assume it can be bug in knife bootstrap)

So i have solved the above problem by using --bootstrap-template

```
knife ec2 server create -E $environment --node-name $TMP_NODE_NAME -f $instance_type -r "recipe[base]" --iam-profile $recipe --bootstrap-template ~/.chef/chef-no-ssl.erb $knife_ec2_flag
```

~/.chef/chef-no-ssl.erb

```
bash -c '
<%= "export https_proxy=\"#{knife_config[:bootstrap_proxy]}\"" if knife_config[:bootstrap_proxy] -%>

distro=`uname -s`

if test "x$distro" = "xSunOS"; then
  if test -d "/usr/sfw/bin"; then
    PATH=/usr/sfw/bin:$PATH
    export PATH
  fi
fi

exists() {
  if command -v $1 &>/dev/null
  then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}

install_sh="https://www.getchef.com/chef/install.sh"
version_string="-v 12.19.36"

if ! exists /usr/bin/chef-client; then
  echo "Installing Chef Client..."
  if exists wget; then
    bash <(wget <%= "--proxy=on " if knife_config[:bootstrap_proxy] %> ${install_sh} -O -) ${version_string}
  elif exists curl; then
    bash <(curl -L <%= "--proxy \"#{knife_config[:bootstrap_proxy]}\" " if knife_config[:bootstrap_proxy] %> ${install_sh}) ${version_string}
  else
    echo "Neither wget nor curl found. Please install one and try again." >&2
    exit 1
  fi
fi

mkdir -p /etc/chef

cat > /etc/chef/validation.pem <<'EOP'
<%= validation_key %>
EOP
chmod 0600 /etc/chef/validation.pem

<% if encrypted_data_bag_secret -%>
cat > /etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret <<'EOP'
<%= encrypted_data_bag_secret %>
EOP
chmod 0600 /etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret
<% end -%>

<%# Generate Ohai Hints -%>
<% unless @chef_config[:knife][:hints].nil? || @chef_config[:knife][:hints].empty? -%>
mkdir -p /etc/chef/ohai/hints

<% @chef_config[:knife][:hints].each do |name, hash| -%>
cat > /etc/chef/ohai/hints/<%= name %>.json <<'EOP'
<%= hash.to_json %>
EOP
<% end -%>
<% end -%>

cat > /etc/chef/client.rb <<'EOP'
<%= config_content.concat "\nssl_verify_mode :verify_none" %>
EOP

cat > /etc/chef/first-boot.json <<'EOP'
<%= first_boot.to_json %>
EOP

echo "Starting first Chef Client run..."

<%= start_chef %>'
```

so if you notice at the end there is client.rb block on which I am concatenating

```
cat > /etc/chef/client.rb <<'EOP'
<%= config_content.concat "\nssl_verify_mode :verify_none" %>
EOP
```